# operator suffix for std::string in c++14

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I install Clang 3.4, and test suffix operator for string literal ""s.

```
#include <string>

//1. using namespace std; // without compile error.
//2. using std::operator ""s; // or without it compile error, too.
// for success compiles, need 1. or 2. line.

int main()
{
    auto s = "hello world"s; 
}
```

If I comment 1 and 2 , I get compile error. But I know in big projects  1.-method is bad,
and 2.-method is stranger.

QA: Can I use operator ""s   without any writing `using namespace std` and `using std::operator ""s` ?

Comment: "2.-method is stranger." Why do you find this strange? Looks quite natural to me.

Comment: Short answer: No, you can't. That's the way it is intended and Clang is correct to require either 1. or 2. It looks like you are just not happy with this and would like to question the decision of how it was defined, but that's not an appropriate Q for SO.

Comment: What the hell... we really need `using` to make a literal suffix work? The mind boggles.

Comment: Presumably you still want to avoid various libraries introducing clashing suffixes ...

Comment: These operators have been defined in an *inline namespace*, so you can as well use `using namespace std::literals::string_literals;` (e.g. inside the function where you use them)

Comment: `using namespace std::literals` also works.

Comment: ...and those additional inline namespaces also show **why** you need the using: Other namespaces might use `s` for seconds, not for strings. You need to make a deliberate decision of which of those operators should be active in which part of your code.

Comment: @DanielFrey As does `std::literals::chrono_literals` (IIRC overload resolution applies, though).

Comment: operator ""s  for string literal  and operator ""s for number literal aren't ambigues.

Comment: @Khurshid Probably a bad example from my side, but the point is that without the using, you could not re-use the `s`-suffix in other contexts in the future. In order not to block this option for future extensions, those existing operators are all in (nested, inline) namespaces.

Comment: "1.-method is bad" - if you do it in the global namespace. It's less bad if you do it in a narrower scope; like within `main` in your example. (And, as discussed above, you don't have to use the whole of `std` to get the suffixes).

Comment: @Daniel Frey CLang shows, warning: user-defined literal suffixes not starting with '_' are reserved [-Wuser-defined-literals], when I overload operator ""s. So suggested do not overload ""s operator.

Comment: @Khurshid Sure. It's reserved for the standard, which might be enhanced in the future.

Comment: simple, I thought, auto s = "hello world"s; should work well without any extra works.

Comment: clearly they should have done `"string things"std::s`.

Comment: You can still do std::operator""s("hello world"), yes? Kind of defeats the purpose, but potentially useful in small scopes where you don't want to bother doing a local using.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Wrapping up the comments:

You have to explicitly pull in those operators with `using`. This is what is intended by the standard. You should consider to pull in only what you need, either

```
using namespace std::literals;
```

or

```
using namespace std::literals::string_literals;
```

depending on your needs, the latter being preferable in case of doubt (only pull in what you need, not more). As with all using declarations or directives, you want to limit them to the smallest scope that is practical.

The reason behind the need to pull the operators in explicitly is that the suffixes might be re-used in future extensions in different contexts.

Comment: std::literals; and std::literals::string_literals; are standard inline namespaces or only for compiler implementation namespaces ?

Comment: @Khurshid They are standardized, thus portable. See "§21.3 String classes [string.classes]" at the end of "Header `<string>` synopsis".

Comment: @Khurshid They standardized these `namespace`s `inline` so that `using std;` would bring in literal operators.  Other result was deemed surprising.

Comment: @DanielFrey:  consider auto s = "hello world"s; std::cout<<typeof(s); Is type of s guaranteed to be deduced as std::string in this case?

Comment: @PravasiMeet Yes, it is guaranteed

Comment: @DanielFrey: ok got it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you found 2nd option strange, that is actually pretty common, you could limit the scope of the "using namespace std" like this:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    auto s = "hello world"s; 
}
```